# How can I send datas from sqlite3 to jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Ok, i know this is a stupid question but i'm new with node.js and jade and sqlite3... so i was wondering how can i send the database dates from a javascript scrit to jade template to populate a table.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM temperatures',
    ['timestamp', 'temp'],
    function(rows){
    rows.forEach(eachRow);
     }
);

function eachRow(row,i,rows){
    console.log(row.timestamp + ": " + row.temp);
    if((i+1) === rows.length){
    }
}

    res.render('index', { title: 'Sergiu Mansion'});
});
```

I've searched everywhere but didn't found anything that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Get data from database. It seems you have this part down.

2) Pass data into the view. You already see some form of it.

```
res.render('index', { yourVar: theData });
```

3) In the template, [iterate over that variable](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/).

```
each val in yourVar
    tr
        // do stuff
```